# É possível um domínio bloquear uma consulta via cUrl?

Tags: php, libcurl

Realizar requisições via `cUrl`, onde o domínio não possui um retorno via JSON/XML/afins, o domínio consultado pode "bloquear" meu IP para consulta via cUrl, ou algo do tipo?

Atualmente, a consulta é realizada via `cUrl`, e é retornado o HTML da página. Apenas isso.

Comment: acrescente o retorno na sua pergunta tbm para consegui te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Você diz o retorno do que vem da consulta cUrl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dificilmente um serviço irá bloquear apenas o `cURL`, isso provavelmente irá ocorrer se estiver usando cabeçalho/corpo incorreto, já de dessa forma o receptor poderá distinguir entre suas requisições via cURL e via não-cURL.

O mais provavelmente, no entanto, é o serviço identificar que está efetuando mais requisições que o permitido (ou seja, atingindo um *rate-limit*), ou que está tendo um comportamento anormal (não realizando as requisições que tipicamente o aplicativo/site iria fazer em condições normais).

---

> Realizar requisições via cUrl, onde o domínio não possui um retorno via JSON/XML/afins, o domínio consultado pode "bloquear" meu IP para consulta via cUrl, ou algo do tipo?

Sim, ele pode bloquear "o cURL" da mesma forma que pode bloquear o navegador. Isso é, qualquer servidor pode recursar suas requisições, independente da forma com que ele é feito (se for via cURL, via navegador, via wget...). O site alvo, por si, tipicamente não irá bloquear "apenas o cURL", ele provavelmente poderá recursar qualquer requisição partindo do seu IP (ou do seu usuário...) ou poderá solicitar algum captcha (ou verificações adicionais) e afins.

Uma maneira de mitigar bloqueios por uso excessivo são: buscar um serviço alternativo, utilizar vários proxies (preferencialmente residenciais e mobile) e balancear requisições entre ele, simular o uso do aplicativo/site de maneira mais próxima de um usuário real e efetuar menos requisições por segundo...

Comment: Obrigado Inkeliz!!

Answer (score 3):

Usando o cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` você pode definir que tipo de requisição pode ser feita para um arquivo (ou rota) no seu servidor de origem.

Dessa forma caso queira permitir apenas requisições do tipo `GET` para a sua página você deverá definfir

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");`
```

No seu arquivo (ou rota) de origem.

Para permitir vários métodos, você pode simplesmente separá-los por `,` (vírgula) desta forma

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, HEADER, OPTIONS");
```

Podendo combinar qualquer quantidade de métodos na lista definida.

Sendo assim caso você esteja fazendo uma requisição **GET** para uma rota que aceite tanto **GET** quanto **POST** o retorno pode ser um HTML pois o retorno da requisição **GET** é um HTML.

Cada uma dessas requisições é recebida pelo servidor e tratada de forma individual, então, respondendo à sua pergunta, existe sim a possibilidade do **Google** jogar seu domínio na *blacklist* por excesso de requisições, te impedindo de fazer buscas por requisição no site por um tempo determinado ou até permanentemente. (Não conheço bem os termos de uso do serviço pra te responder com certeza)

Comment: Perfeito, Erlon. Muito obrigado pela resposta.
No caso, a requisição é feita ao Google Imagens, onde é passado o parâmetro de consulta via GET.
Exemplo: https://www.google.com.br/search?sout=2&biw=1024&bih=548&tbm=isch&q=ferrari+2019

Meu receio é o Google bloquear o meu domínio, porém como eles usam "get" para realizar tais pesquisas, com base no que você falou então é certo do meu domínio não ser bloqueado. Correto?

Comment: Entendi agora o bloqueio que você diz, nesse caso específico é melhor você usar as APIs do google para fazer essas pesquisas. https://developers.google.com/photos/

Comment: Este que você passou é do Google Photos. Eu preciso de obter as imagens do Google Images (pesquisa pública de imagens).
A API que eu conheço pra imagens é paga. Preciso de uma gratuita.

Comment: @RayanMarcus verdade, realmente os que eu procurei são todas pagas, embora sejam muito boas.
Mas respondendo à sua pergunta, existe sim a possibilidade do Google jogar seu domínio na blacklist por excesso de requisições, vou editar a resposta adicionando esse comentário pra ficar mais condizente com o que você estava procurando.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Erlon!